# Drupal 7 Webform settings: how to change the default text in button "next page"?

Tags: 7, theming, forms, webforms

I have created a webform with drupal 7 with two pages with "pagebreak" field, but when i go in mysite webform and i view the webform at the bottom of the page there is the button "next page": i have to change the text in this button... and also probably set an image at the place of simple text "next page"..
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hook_form_alter to alter things in forms like button texts. This can in drupal 7 be done in both the theme and a module, but in Drupal 6 it can only be done in a module.